# Background Image resize: Responsive theme

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am running into some issues with my full screen background image on my webpage. It looks great via desktop browsers (IE, Chrome, Safari...) but when the responsive theme CSS kicks in it does not resize to the correct resolution.

For desktop and responsive CSS:

```
background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

I have tried using different jpeg sizes depending on the media max-width, I have also tried just applying the background image with only a `left:0px;` and I have tried `background-size:contain;` and `background-size: cover !important;` but no success. What is most frustrating is: in firefox debugger > responsive view > it's flawless but via a real phone/tablet the background is blown up and pixelated (of course you cannot expect the debugger to work).

This is also difficult because the website is technically all one page... and each "virtual page" is an individual div.

Firefox responsive:

[image: Firefox responsive]

Actual iPhone responsive (it is hard to see but on the next page there is a new image and it is huge):

[image: Actual iPhone responsive]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the key to resizing the image:

```
background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat local center top; 
        -webkit-background-size: 125% auto;
```

Play around with percent and use this ^ webkit

http://kimili.com/journal/the-flexible-scalable-background-image-redux

^ for further reading

Comment: I have found this to work better: 
`background: url(../content/cheetah.jpg) 50% 50% / cover no-repeat fixed;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code, if that works for you:

```
background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
 -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
 -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: This did indeed fit the entire image onto the page however it is extremely distorted as it did not scale.

Comment: You can try by changing the % for the small screens.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I could think of is to set a media query appropriate for smaller / mobile screens and set there a `background-size:auto 100%`, as the main problem that I understand is to make your image fit the whole height.

Comment: That is essentially doing what cover or contain is doing. Which works when in testing the responsive theme via a desktop browser but breaks when on a mobile device. I don't understand.

Comment: I also use those values for background-size but there are some mobile browsers that don't support those values.